# Incorrect orientation in iPhone developing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've developed a universal application for iPhone and iPad.
Using the "Supported interface orientations" option in Targets (inside the Xcode project) I've setted up the desired configuration, one for iPhone and another one for iPad.
No problem with iPhone (5.1 and 6.1) but with iPad I see that in 5.1 firmware the orientation is not correct (not as setted up as written before). For iPad with iOS 6.1 the app works correctly.

I've read another stackoverflow's question with a resolution: the problem will be correct introducing the following code.

```
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

In my case the problem is still present. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

The above method in your case always returned YES (int bigger than 0), this way it will return no for all other interface orientations.

You might want to refactor your code to support both landscape orientations though, it is a bad practice to lock the view to only one landscape orientation.